# Elem bind not working when transclude is set to true

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have been trying to transclude content of an element, and manipulate it's display property by binding `click` event to one of the children of the element. But it doesn't seem to be working.

```
app.directive('apple', function(){

  function link(scope, elem, attr, ctrl, transclude) {
    elem('a.link').bind('click', function() {
      ('ul.menu').toggleClass('active');
    });

    transclude(scope, function(clone) {
      elem.html(clone);
    });
  }

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    link: link
  };

});
```

HTML:

```
<apple>
  <a class="link" href="#">Show</a>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>linky</li>
  </ul>
</apple>
```

Any idea what's going on? link to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pb2q4zj4/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case you're really trying to make a drop down menu, rather than working out how transclude works, here's a simpler way;

**View**

```
<div ng-app ng-init="show=false">
    <div>
      <a ng-click="show = !show">Show</a>
      <ul ng-show="show">
        <li>linky</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('app', []);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4oq1zLsg/